# NameError: global name 'myText' is not defined

Tags: python, user-interface

So I'm trying to build an insult generator that will take lists, randomize the inputs, and show the randomized code at the push of a button.

Right now, the code looks like...

```
import Tkinter
import random


section1 = ["list of stuff"]
section2 = ["list of stuff"]
section3 = ["list of stuff"]

class myapp(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid() # creates grid layout manager where we can place our widgets within the window

        button = Tkinter.Button(self, text=u"Generate!", command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1, row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()

        label = Tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor='w', fg='white', bg='green')
        label.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Oh hi there !")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.resizable(True, False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())

    def generator():
        a = random.randint(0, int(len(section1))-1)
        b = random.randint(0, int(len(section2))-1)
        c = random.randint(0, int(len(section3))-1)
        myText = "You are a "+ section1[a]+" "+section2[b]+'-'+section3[c]+"! Fucker."
        return myText

    def OnButtonClick(self):
        self.labelVariable.set(myText + "(You clicked the button !)") 
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = myapp(None) # Instantiates the class
    app.title('Random Insult Generator') # Names the window we're creating.
    app.mainloop() # Program will loop indefinitely, awaiting input
```

Right now, the error it's giving is that the `myText` isn't defined.
Any thoughts on how to fix it?

**Edit:**
The error message is...

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "...", line 41, in OnButtonClick
    self.labelVariable.set(myText+"(You clicked the button !)")
NameError: global name 'myText' is not defined
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? The error is obviously occurring in `OnButtonClick` and indeed, you have not defined `myText` in that function.

Comment: Is there any chance that you might turn your skills towards writing _useful_ software at some point? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Well, he might have some people he needs to insult but maybe he doesn't have the time to think about insults ☺ (that's actually a smile, but at this font size it looks like a frown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If im dissectiong your code properly, you need to set def generator(): outside of the class you've defined; aka, make it a local function, not a method of myapp. secondly, you are trying to use the myText variable inside your onButtonClick method, but as your error states, it is not defined. in order to use the data your generator function is sending, you need to call the function. Just treat the last line of your def generator as a placeholder.

your accessor method should look like this:

```
def OnButtonClick(self):
    self.labelVariable.set(generator()+"(You clicked the button !)") 
    #self.entry.focus_set()
    #self.entry.selection_range(0,Tkinter.END)
```

(the entry widget is not needed, and you have not called .pack() on it yet ;) )

and your generator function should be outside of your class.

Alternatively, you could leave the generator function inside your class as a method, but you would need to add the self. arguement as a parameter to it:

```
def generator(self):
```

and add self.generator() when you call it in your button click event method.

Cheers!

Comment: +1 on the correct answer plus the suggestion of moving the `generator` function outside of the class.  It really has no business be inside the class as it stands right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def OnButtonClick(self):
    myText = self.generator() # CALL IT!
    self.labelVariable.set(myText+"(You clicked the button !)") 
    self.entry.focus_set()
    self.entry.selection_range(0,Tkinter.END)
```

AND

```
def generator(self):....
```

Comment: That should be a lowercase `generator()` and should be called with `self.generator()` and `self` should be added as an arg to generator as in `def generator(self)`

Answer (score -2):

change with OnButtonClick function's second line and replace myText with generator()

Comment: That will jut change the name error to "generator" instead of "myText".